# Measure progress in recursive search

Tags: c#, recursion, progress

I have a recursive search, which searches for files with a specified name in a whole directory.
This needs quite some time and I want to show a progressbar, which shows atleast some progress (I don't care if the progress is just measured by the number of files or directory or the actual size of them).

Following (recursive code) performs the search:

```
private void searchFolder(PortableDeviceFolder parent, ref List<PortableDeviceFolder> result, string filename)
{
    foreach (var item in parent.Files)
    {

        if (item is PortableDeviceFolder)
        {
            searchFolder((PortableDeviceFolder)item, ref result, filenames);
        }
        else if ((String.Compare(item.Name, filename)==0))
        {
            result.Add(parent);
            Console.WriteLine("Found file in: " + parent.Name);
        }    
    }
}
```

I couldn't figure out how to get the progress. I was thinking about an easy algorithm which measures the same percentage for each file and folder;

- Documents (10%)

  - privat(10%/3)
  - work(10%/3)

    - project1 (10%/3/2)
    - project2 (10%/3/2)
  - familly (10%/3)
- ...

and so on.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to implement this in the recursive search.
Has anybody the time to give me an example?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it's going to involve adding a new `int` parameter to the method signature that tells you the recursion depth so you can know what fraction of the whole each level contributes.

Comment: @adv12 But knowing the recursion depth is not enough, I also need to know how many files or folders are in each directory to get the correct fraction.

Comment: Agreed.  You'll need both.

Comment: Might be better off showing "now searching this/directory..." and change it as things bounce around to show work happening. Otherwise you'd really need to scan the directories before you scan the directories...

Comment: It's a well known, non-trivial problem. See http://xkcd.com/612/

Comment: I just want to have a progressbar which is not completly random and ends at 100% when the search finishes, so the user gets some kind of feedback.
Showing text with the current directory is an option but it doesn't fit for me.

Comment: Since you don't have the necessary information you can't really do it. If you want to go beyond simply showing a live progressbar (which is the only proper solution imo) you could progress slower and slower. If you can't make an estimate and have no knowledge about the distribution the problem can't be solved.

Comment: ..But maybe you can collect the folders only (`Directory.GetDirectories`) and then use their count as the base for the progress. The time spent on the initial scan will probably be saved through faster access times during the file scan..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenter TaW's suggestion that you can count the directories to use as the basis for progress is good. But there's a small problem, not with the suggestion itself but in the way your code seems to be implemented.

It's not clear from your question what `PortableDeviceFolder` is. But it appears to abstract the difference between a file and a folder, returning both from the `Files` property. Given that the most time-consuming aspect of your processing is likely the actual retrieval of the file names for a given directory, then if the only mechanism `PortableDeviceFolder` has to return the directories in a given directory is that `Files` property, you'd have to wind up enumerating all the files along with the directories, ignoring the files returned for the purpose of generating the count.

In other words, getting the count will take almost as long as the actual search for the given name.

So, for the purpose of this answer I will assume that the `PortableDeviceFolder` class has another property `Folders` which returns *just* the directories themselves. With such a property, then we can take advantage of the suggestion TaW's offered.

First, you'll need to get that count. A method to do that would look like this:

```
private int CountFolders(PortableDeviceFolder rootFolder)
{
    return rootFolder.Folders.Select(folder => CountFolders(folder)).Sum() + 1;
}
```

There will be a slight delay before any progress is shown, because of course there's no useful way to predict how long the above will take. But it should be relatively brief, since we are looking only at the directories and not all the files.

To be able to update the progress while the processing is going, we should run the search in a separate thread and use `Dispatcher.Invoke()` to update the `ProgressBar.Value` property. The search method then looks like this:

```
private void SearchFolder(PortableDeviceFolder parent,
    List<PortableDeviceFolder> result, string fileName, IProgress<int> progress)
{
    foreach (var item in parent.Files)
    {
        PortableDeviceFolder folder = item as PortableDeviceFolder;

        if (folder != null)
        {
            SearchFolder(folder, result, fileName, progress);
        }
        else if (item.Name.Equals(fileName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            result.Add(parent);
        }
    }

    progress.Report(1);
}
```

NOTE: it's not clear to me why you were passing the `result` parameter by-reference. That doesn't seem to be needed, and so I've change it to a regular by-value parameter.

In your UI code, you might call it like this:

```
private async void SearchFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;

    button.IsEnabled = false;

    string searchPath = textBlock1.Text, searchText = textBox1.Text;
    List<PortableDeviceFolder> folders = new List<PortableDeviceFolder>();
    PortableDeviceFolder rootFolder = new WindowsDirectoryFolder(searchPath);

    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    progressBar1.Maximum = await Task.Run(() => CountFolders(rootFolder));

    Progress<int> progress =
        new Progress<int>(increment => progressBar1.Value += increment);

    await Task.Run(() => SearchFolder(rootFolder, folders, searchText, progress));

    listBox1.ItemsSource = folders;
    button.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Note that here we execute both the `CountFolders()` and the `SearchFolder()` method asynchronously, to ensure the UI remains responsive while the work is being done.

The above is from a simple WPF program I wrote to demonstrate the technique, but it can be adapted to Winforms or other GUI frameworks without difficulty. The basic idea remains the same.