# How can I set maximum value of progressBar in recursive method

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a recursive method which goes through files in folders, also I have a progressbar, how can I set maximum value of it?

```
using System.IO;

private void Start()
{
    progressBar1.Maximum = ??
}


private void GetFiles(string path)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
        {
            Method(file);
        }
        foreach (string folder in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            GetFiles(folder);
        }
    }
    catch { }
}

private void Method(string file)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(file);
    progressBar1.Increment(1);
}
```

Comment: Please take time to properly format your question body; and add the proper tags (`winforms` perhaps?); and please ask an actual question; from what you've posted, it's not exactly clear what you want to do.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to know. Obviously, you have found out how to add a maximum value, as you have already written the line `progressBar1.Maximum = ??`. So, simply insert a maximum value: `progressBar1.Maximum = 42;` This answers your question, but probably does not solve your problem, which means that **you have not described your problem in your question.**

Comment: Btw. your code contains three syntactic errors (or did; two have been fixed at least here on SO): **1.** you are missing a closing `}`, **2.** the `catch { }` is inside the `try { }` instead of succeeding it, and **3.** you are assigning a value to `progressBar1.Maximum` outside of a method body.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Measure progress in recursive search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987175/measure-progress-in-recursive-search)

Comment: Please see the answered question I've proposed as a duplicate. It is almost exactly the same question. The main difference is that in your case, you can count all the files instead of just the folders, and of course you will use the `Directory` class directly instead of the wrapper the OP in the other question was using. Also: it seems to me that you can forego the `ProgressBar` altogether here; run the code in the background, and use the progressive updating of the `ListView` as the user's progress indication.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not really about the progressbar (you already discovered the `Maximum` property), but about determining the number of files in a directory before enumerating them. That cannot be done reliably.

You can better use a continuous animation (spinner) to indicate on-going progress. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/635958/62662) on how to do that.